AKS internal load balancer with Appgateway frontend
Need step to set up an Azure Application Gateway in front of an existing Nginx setup with an internal load balancer.
Application gateway using http 80 and listner 80.
So far getting below when set up
Time taken by the backend to respond to application gateway's health probe is more than the time-out threshold in the probe configuration. Either increase the time-out threshold in the probe configuration or resolve the backend issues. Note: for default probe, the http timeout is 30s. To learn more visit

Share your app gw configuration. I have a feeling there is some error in config there. Please checkout my below steps and match it with your environment

Welcome Andrew.

I have a feeling that something is not correct in your application gateway (appgw) setup.  Please checkout Tutorial: Create an application gateway
First as usual create your aks and deploy your nginx inside it

Now first verify if using the nginx external IP address you are able to access it or not?

Looks good. So far, no issues.
next troubleshooting you need to do is-
Go to your app gw / create your app gw or edit it to use the same VNET as your aks cluster and inside that create your subnet and link that.

Once that is done, ensure you have placed the nginx external IP as the target IP under the backend targets

and also, under backend setting, the port and protocol are 80 and http

If you choose https i.e. port 443 and your nginx on the other hand is mapped to 80, you'll get error
Next check you do is under backend setting ensure you choose

Once you configure and deploy your application gateway correctly you should be able to access it via the app gw public ip


References:

Troubleshoot backend health issues in Application Gateway
Troubleshooting bad gateway errors in Application Gateway


"Thank you for the steps. However, what if we want to use an internal ILB as the backend? The application is working when accessed via the public ILB IP, and we have switched NGINX to a private IP and redeployed the internal ILB. It  works internally within the VNet when accessed from a VM inside the same VNet (the NGINX service external IP points to the ILB private IP), but when add private ip of ilb to appgateway back end we getting 502 errors

Now it looks like, after setting the backend settings and configuring the hostname override to pick the hostname from the backend target, we are getting.
" Received invalid status code: 404 in the backend server’s HTTP response. As per the health probe configuration, 200-399 is the acceptable status code. Either modify probe configuration or resolve backend issues. To learn more visit - https://aka.ms/StatusCodeMismatch."
